# Calculate difference between time fields & show case seconds

Tags: formula, formula-field

I'm trying to build a text formula field to showcase the difference between two-time fields & display hours minutes and seconds.

I've created the below formula and able to calculate hours & minutes. Currently, I'm not able to calculate seconds now. Could you please help me.

```
TEXT(FLOOR((Speed_to_Dial_main__c - CreatedDate)*24)) &' Hr '& 
TEXT(FLOOR(((((Speed_to_Dial_main__c - CreatedDate)*24)-
FLOOR((Speed_to_Dial_main__c - CreatedDate)*24))*60)))&' Mins'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following your example, something like ...

```
TEXT(FLOOR((Speed_to_Dial_main__c - CreatedDate)*24)) &' Hr '& 
TEXT(MOD(FLOOR((Speed_to_Dial_main__c - CreatedDate)*24*60), 60)) & ' Mins '&
TEXT(MOD(FLOOR((Speed_to_Dial_main__c - CreatedDate)*24*60*60), 60)) & ' Secs'
```

Comment: Works like charm.thanks